# How to test if a time variable is in a series or not in python

Tags: python, time, alignment, series

Background: Sometimes we need to take a date which is a month after than the original timestamp, since not all days are trading days, some adjustments must be made.

I extracted the index of stock close price, getting a time series with lots of timestamps of trading days.

```
trading_day_glossory = stock_close_full.index
```

Now, given a datetime-format variable **date**, with the following function, the program should return me the day variable indicating a trading day. But indeed it did not. The if condition is never evoked, eventually it added up to 9999:99:99 and reported error.

```
def return_trading_day(day,trading_day_glossory): 
    while True:
        day = day + relativedelta(days=1)
        if day in trading_day_glossory:
            break
```

I reckon that comparing a timestamp with a datetime is problematic, so I rewrote the first part of my function in this way:

```
trading_day_glossory = stock_close_full.index
trading_day_glossory = trading_day_glossory.to_pydatetime()

# Error message: OverflowError: date value out of range
```

However this change makes no difference. I further tested some characteristics of the variables involved:

```
testing1 = trading_day_glossory[20] # returns a datetime variable say 2000-05-08 00:00:00
testing2 = day # returns a datetime variable say 2000-05-07 00:00:00
```

What may be the problem and what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: btw The trading_day_glossory variable contains dates in a considerably long time span and will 100% cover the date indicated by the **date** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is going on because the errors cannot be reproduced from your codes and variables.

However, you can try [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) to find the first timestamp not earlier than a given date in a sorted time series by binary search:

```
trading_day_glossory.searchsorted(day)
```

It's way better than comparing values in a while loop.